# Saving data from Contact form 7 to ftp server

Tags: php, wordpress, web, plugins, ftp

playing around i finally figured it out... obviously thanks to @vard.

the following code send the file to the required FTP. Gonna run afew more tests and just make sure there are no more errors,

minor issue,. the Sumbit circle keeps turning even though request went through. should be easy to sort out though. Hope this helps someone out there.

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'log_cf7');


 function log_cf7($WPCF7_ContactForm) {
   $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
   $data = $submission->get_posted_data();


   $data2 = print_r($data, true);

   $myfile = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/tempFile.txt","wb");

   fwrite($myfile, $data2);
   $ftp_server="-";
   $ftp_username="-";
   $ftp_userpass="-";
   $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to server");
   $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
   if(ftp_put($ftp_conn,"newdata.txt",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/tempFile.txt",FTP_ASCII))
    {
        print("yay");
    }
    else
    {
        print("f...");
    }
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Comment: Awesome man! Works great for me, except the spinning circle. Did you ever figured that out? Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Marcio, unfortunately the project was cancelled and I never solved it. :/.. id suggest opening a new question regarding this as I havn't touched php again since early 2016 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action in order to process your function before the mail is sent. Add the following to your *functions.php* file:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'log_cf7');
function log_cf7($WPCF7_ContactForm) {
   $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
   $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
   // do your ftp log here
}
```

`$data` is an array containing your form content (key = input name, value = input value).

To write to another server you can make use of [PHP FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php).

Comment: I have built up what i need, (i think) just not finding the right place to put it. attempted main functions.php.  broke website. attempted plugin functions.php. did nothing... any suggestions :)?

Comment: Well you should use the _functions.php_ from your theme. If it break the website, then you should have a PHP error (maybe a syntax error). Could you try to set the `WP_DEBUG` constant in your _wp-config.php_ file to `true` to see if any error message display?

Comment: Ah I see that you updated your question with the new code. The problem is that you send `$data` to `ftp_put` as third argument, though [`ftp_put`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ftp-put.php) except a path (string) to the file you want to put to the distant server, not an array as you currently do. You need to create first the file locally in a temporary folder, send it to the distant then delete the temporary file once the transfert is complete. Let me know if you experienced issues with this.

Comment: Thanks for your time, gonna quickly make those changes and see if it works. :)

Comment: ive updated code and given a error log, searching for issue as well. I just read your comment again.. will my temp file work or does it need a exact path?

Comment: You added the code in the wrong _functions.php_ - you shouldn't touch the one in _wp-includes_, it's part of the Wordpress core. Use the _functions.php_ located in your theme folder instead (in `wp-content/themes/[name of your theme]/functions.php`)

Comment: ai my bad. first time adding this stuff.. its now not throwing errors. but as i hit send on the cf7 form, circle just keeps turning and turning.

Comment: Look into your browser console, you should see an ajax request being sent by the form after submission. If you look into the response tab you should see if the script returns any error.

Comment: empty.. not even a request sent

Comment: Ah just thought of something: you shouldn't echo "Succesfully uploaded". CF7 expect a json string as return, so if you echo stuff before it will consider that the form submission failed, then it will stay on the circle loader.

Comment: Are you using firebug or the native console? If you're using the chrome native console go on the network tab and click on "XHR" to see the ajax request sent. The console need to be opened when you submit the form to make sure that it record stuffs.

Comment: ah i see.. thx.. ok it seems my temp file isnt cutting it, will make a proper temp file with path available. will post error in up top. possibly my ftp has an issue too

Comment: Could you try with `fwrite` instead of `file_put_contents` ?

Comment: will attempt and get back to you.. changing afew things as well. heading away for abit though so ill let u know how it goes tomorrow, Thank you for all your assistance. have really saved me a load of time and effort, as well as teaching me so much.